# Can't install Firefox in Kali Linux

Tags: firefox, installation, kali-linux

I'm unable to install Firefox in Kali Linux 2.0. Please guide me through this. I get this error message:

```
gpg: "–keyserver" not a key ID: skipping
gpg: "keyserver.ubuntu.com" not a key ID: skipping
gpg: no keyserver known (use option --keyserver)
gpg: keyserver receive failed: bad URI
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYyz7.png]

Answer (score 2):

Note it says "use option `--keyserver`", and it looks like you used `–keyserver`; you're missing a dash/hyphen, so it's screwing up your entire command.

Actually, looking closer at your screenshot and your example log entries, it looks like you actually used an ["en dash"](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html) (or perhaps an "em dash") instead of a hyphen:

[image]

My guess would be that you've copied and pasted that command from someplace, and something along the way 'autocorrected' the double-dash to the en dash.

The correct commands are as follows:

```
apt-get remove iceweasel
echo -e "\ndeb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C1289A29
apt-get update
apt-get install firefox-mozilla-build
```