# Issue with reinstalling iceweasel

Tags: linux

I uninstalled iceweasel because I was trying to get a different version of Firefox and it didn't work out so I reinstalled it. Then I did that again but this time it won't reinstall. I tried Apt-get install iceweasel and it says reading package lists...done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... done
Package iceweasel is not available, but it is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.

I have no idea what to do and it's very important that this is fixed soon.

Comment: The Iceweasel project has been discontinued.  Even if there is a version still in the repository, it will be outdated.  Different versions of Firefox are available.  Can you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: Well I need some type of browser. Could you inform me on how to get another version?

Comment: Can you clarify what you need in another version?  (i.e., why not use the latest Firefox?)  You had originally posted the question as an answer and I thought I remembered that you're using Kali.  What is available in the Kali repo?  What version do you need or what are you trying to achieve with a different version?  Are you averse to loading Firefox from a tarball from Mozilla?  Are you looking for the latest version or a specific older version?

Comment: I want the latest version of Firefox but I don't know how to install it. Could you tell me how? I'm sorry I'm inexperienced.

Comment: Check out this answer to a previous question: [Can't install Firefox in Kali Linux](http://superuser.com/a/1025860/364367).  That may give you everything you need.  Additional alternatives: http://superuser.com/questions/322376/how-to-install-the-real-firefox-on-debian/322379#322379